# Voltage-tunable capacitors -- how do they work, specifically those from Murata?

Tags: capacitor, varactor

I'm curious about how MURATA variable capacitors work, for example, parts from the family LXRW0YV330-056. As far as I can tell, these are not semiconductor varactors, but based on some other physical principle; does anyone know what it is? There is no information on the data sheets except that they are "ceramic".

My interest is that I would like a voltage-tuned capacitor where the input capacitance on the control voltage line is as small as possible, but the capacitance swing per input volt is as large as possible. Also, I would like these to work at cryogenic temperatures, where semiconductor varactors tend to fail. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question.  As you point out, Murata seems to have deliberately left out any information about the mechanism of action, possibly to protect a trade secret.  Could be some type of MEMS variable capacitor structure.

Comment: Maybe the external voltage is used to polarize the media similar to how a bias reduces the capacitance of an MLCC? Could possibly test that by measuring the impedance between the bias port and the capacitor terminals.

Comment: The C-V curve looks very much like a X7R cap

Comment: There's no tempco listed in the data sheet, and the temperature range is quite restricted. If they are ferroelectric capacitors, I would not expect them to get down to cryo temperatures any better than varactors.

Comment: My practical experiences from trying that chip: 0.4 x 0.4 mm chip is really small; the capacitance adjustment somehow didn't seem to work very well for wideband signals and is sensitive to DC bias on the RF pins.

Answer (score 13):

See US [9,047,524](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/f7/47/c3/9681b9fdc9d268/US9047524.pdf)

The structure shown in the patent incorporates the resistor network R21-R25 whereas the capacitors OP mentions have those resistors (where needed) externally, but otherwise the function is exactly similar.

The principle is a series array of ferroelectric capacitors with bias voltage applied in parallel through high-value resistors that are incorporated in the IC-like structure.

[image]

From the [datasheet](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807789002782/M19X-LXRW-056.pdf?1633442419000) you can see the relationship between the bias voltage (P13 to P14) on the capacitance (P11 to P12):

[image]

In this case, C1..C6 are about 200pF each at 0V bias.

I think you could make something like this with small ceramic capacitors and discrete resistors. For example, this Murata capacitor (curve from Murata's online generator):

[image]

So with 6 capacitors you'd get a change from about 17.5nF to 13nF for a bias change from 2V to 15V (typically, unlike the purpose-built part there are no guarantees).

If it's not obvious- the AC voltage across each capacitor would be 1/6 of the total voltage, so the resulting effects of the capacitance modulation (eg. distortion) will be much reduced compared to one capacitor. It's not quite as effective as the back-to-back varactor method, of course.

Comment: Thanks for finding that!  I expect you are right.  So if I understand correctly, I'd expect input capacitance at P13 i that diagram to be gong to be larger than that between P11 and P12 at low frequencies?

Comment: P13 and P14 are the bias terminals of the variable capacitor. The capacitance between P11 and P12 is inversely related to the voltage between P13 and P14.